# View under my container view is not showing up on iOS device

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, autolayout, storyboard

I currently have a `UIContainerView` and a `UIView` in a view controller, the container view is at the top and the view is at the bottom, it is a small rectangle in which I will put a banner ad. I have constrained both of these things in my view controller but when run the view at the bottom does not show. Below is the Storyboard and the iPhone 5s it is running on.

Here is my device, as you can see it only shows my container view (which has a table view in it), and it does not show the purple view below it:

[image: iPhone example]

Here is my storyboard:

[image: Storyboard]

Here are my constraints on my view controller:

[image: Constraints]

Comment: What is the View.top = top + 617? And why you have next two identical View.top = Container View.bottom?

Comment: Those are auto layout constraints that were added @noir_eagle

Comment: @noir_eagle I remove that top + 617 and that fixed it, if you add an answer I will accept it.

Comment: ok, I've added it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove `View.top = top + 617` constraint and that would fix it.